# Google Apps (free) domain locked out after trial expired for G. Apps Business

Tags: google-workspace

I signed up for a free trial for google apps business for my domain, but decided that I didn't need it. Let it expire, and now can't log in to the domain any more.

I did get one message saying that the domain was on hold due to billing issues, and that I needed to downgrade, but there was no link to do the downgrade. I accidentally signed in as another user while in the control panel, and now I can't get back in as any user.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen to me. Call the [Google Apps support phone](http://support.google.com/a/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=contacting_support.html) number and ask them to complete the downgrade to the standard service, but you should be able to get into your control panel no matter what.